# Laurent series of $\log(z)\sin(1/(z-1))$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I would like to calculate the Laurent series of $$\log(z)\sin \left(\frac{1}{z-1} \right)$$ I have developed  separately $\log z$ et the sinus and tried to multiplied them terms by terms but it is complicated. Is there another simplier way?

Comment: about what point?

Comment: The developments are around the singularity points. z=0 and z=1. This function is analytic in C exept for z=0 and z=1.
The Laurent serie around 1 should converge in any points Inside the cercle center 1 and radius less than 1. 
The Laurent serie around 0 should converge in any points Inside the cercle center 0 and radius less than 1. 
How to compute the coeffiecient?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we expand about $\zeta=z-1$, then

$$\log{(1+\zeta)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \zeta^k}{k} $$
$$\sin{\frac1{\zeta}} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)!\,\zeta^{2 n+1}} $$

There really is no substitute for multiplying the series out.  The best you can do is write

$$\log{(1+\zeta)} \sin{\frac1{\zeta}} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} a_m \zeta^m $$

and compute the coefficients $a_m$ as needed.  As an example, let's compute the residue, or the coefficient of $\zeta^{-1}$.  By multiplying the terms out, you can show that the residue is

$$a_{-1} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(4 k)!}  =  \left (\cosh{1} + \cos{1} \right ) - 2 = 2 \left (\sinh^2{\frac12} - \sin^2{\frac12} \right )$$

Comment: Don't you have to multiply an infinite serie by an another infinite serie? Are sure than the computation of a coefficient is not another infinite serie??

Comment: @ClaudeOlier: that is precisely what I did.  Each coefficient is another infinite series.  It turns out that the residue is a recognizable one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints and a bit of example**

Use the substitution

$$z - 1 = u$$

so that

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{3!u^3} + \cdot$$

and

$$\log(z) = \log(u+1) = u - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{3} - \cdot $$

In this way you get simply

$$\left(\frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{3!u^3}\right)\cdot \left(u - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{3}\right) = -\frac{1}{6u^2} + \frac{1}{12u} + \frac{17}{18} - \frac{u}{2} + \frac{u^2}{3}$$

Comment: If this is not incorrect, then it is sloppy.  The argument of the sine in the neighborhood of $z=1$ is not small, so how can you justify its expansion there?  The answer is that sine is entire and thus may be represented by an **infinite** series almost everywhere.  In this way, you need the entire infinite series representation of the sine for this to make any sense.  By only showing a piece if it (and not even using ellipses to show that the series goes on), your answer is dangerously misleading.  For example, the residue you are showing is wrong.

Comment: @RonGordon If you have time and will, could you answer to the question then? I wanted to give just a hint, but I did' know it was THAT wrong >.< I'm sorry!